# How access a void functions another file in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am working with API keys and I need to be able to access the same unique API from two different screens. Basically, I need the dataKey variable in both screens, and I get the dataKey variable from the getKey() function, which has a get method that fetches the key. Right now the getKey() function is in one of the files (todolist.dart), but I don't know how to access it from my other file (add_new_item.dart).

Answer (score 0):

Create a class, define the function getKey() inside the class. Then import the file where the Class is created. Then Use ClassName.getKey() syntax.